# Conversion of EGM96 to NAVD88

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, dem, datum, srtm

I am new to ArcGIS and geoids/ellipsoids, and I want to convert a dataset in EGM96 (the USGS SRTM DEMs) to NAVD88. I have the SRTM dataset from NASA downloaded and open in ArcGIS as .hgt files.

I have downloaded VDatum from NOAA, which lists the EGM96 geoid on its webpage, but when I try to use the tool there are no EGM geoids available to select.

I have also found this https://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm96/binary/binarygeoid.html  which seems to be code written in FORTRAN, available to the public, to allow conversion of EGM96 to NAVD88. However the input doesn't seem to be .hgt files, which is what the SRTM dataset is. Also, this looks difficult to implement (and I'm not too familiar with FORTRAN77) and I'm wondering if there is something more recent.

Does anyone have a (relatively) simple approach to this? I don't think ArcGIS will perform the conversion. I have version 10.6. I haven't tried it myself as I'm new to ArcGIS but this is what I've read so far.

I am new to this topic so writing my own code for this is not something I can try at the moment (would take months).

Comment: [Edit: I tried looking into ArcGIS 10.6, and under Layer Properties-Display there is an option for orthorectification. However, it's grayed out-- and I'm not sure this is simply a "Display" issue. Also, the SRTM dataset is described by USGS as being in EGM96, but ArcGIS is assuming it is WGS84 and is reading it as such.]